# how to run two processes one after another in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, asynchronous, threadpool

I am trying to run two commands, one after the another. My code looks like:

```
baking.bake()
print "baking completed"
```

My goal is to run `baking.bake()` (which takes around 1 min to complete) and immediately afterwards want to print "baking started". Finally, when the baking is done I want to print "baking done". In essence: how can I run `bake()` asynchronously?

here is my backing.py file

```
# Bake a texture map
from cgkit.cmds import load, worldObject, listWorld
from cgkit.rmshader import RMMaterial, RMShader
from cgkit.sceneglobals import Globals



def bake():
        Globals(
            bake = True,
            resolution = (512, 512),
            pixelsamples = (2,2),
            output = "ao_map.tif",
            displaymode = "rgba"
        )

        # Load the model
        load("singleSofa.obj")
        # Obtain a reference to the model
        model = worldObject("small_sofa_dark_grey")

        # Set the bake material
        mat = RMMaterial(
            surface = RMShader(
                "bake_ao.sl",
                samples = 1000,
            )
        )

        model.setMaterial(mat)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want. If you want to run the first line then the second, that is exactly what is going to happen. What do you want to avoid?

Comment: @infostacker : i want to wait till the first line command completes completely i.e. for around 1 min around (time it is runned is not fixed it may vary)

Comment: How is this different from what your code does?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Exactly my point.

Comment: @LevLevitsky : but here when i run my program it is prining baking completed and then it is starting the process of baking.bake()

Comment: Does baking.bake() creates a new process or thread?

Comment: Please show the code of the baking.bake function.

Comment: @infostacker : no baking is file name and bake() is a function in it , just thats it

Comment: That function is probably dispatching another process, which does the work. Otherwise the result would be exactly what you want.

Comment: @user3453803 I don't think anyone's going to be able to help until you show the source of `baking.bake()` - whatever it appears to be doing is a non-blocking operation and returning control immediately for your `print` to happen...

Comment: @JonClements : i edited my question plz refer to it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [multiprocessing module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing), as below:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def something(i):
    time.sleep(2)
    return i+i

pool = Pool(processes=1)
res = pool.apply_async(something, [2])
print "Started something, waiting..."
# ...
print "Done with something. Result was: %s" % (res.get())
```

So in your scenario we can just do something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Create baking object and so forth.
# ...

pool = Pool(processes=1)
res = pool.apply_async(baking.bake)
print "Baking started"

# Then we do something while we wait...

res.get()
print "Baking done."
```

Comment: here also it is printing the message first and going there for executing

Comment: @user3453803: please accept as solution, if this worked for you.

Comment: We spawn a new process (yes, process) and call it asynchronously which basically equates to "doing something in the background and letting it us know when it is done" instead of waiting for it. You should read a bit up on threads, processes and more importantly asynchronous-concepts if you are interested. Some languages (javascript++) are async by default, whilst Python and most other languages are not, without using libraries.

Comment: @user3453803: there is also quite a bit of information in the documentation, which I've provided a link to in my answer.

Comment: ok i got u we must include libraries to archeive async execution in python but i am asking what is "something" in the code ????

Comment: Ah. That is just to show an example. `something` is the function I define in line 4. So just call it like: `pool.apply_async(baking.bake())` instead.

Comment: sry sir here it is not waiting and executing synchronously and even it is throwing error likw NoneType object is not callable

Comment: Well, have you created the `baking` object? Where does it throw that error? You have to save the result of calling `apply_async()` and later call `.get()` on that result.

Comment: i had copy pasted the same code u posted in my project file by replacing something by bakepass.bake() that's it

Comment: Well, impossible to debug without looking at your complete code. But I extended my answer now, to fit better with your question.

Comment: my complete code is in the question itself see it
it is a baking file using CGKIT so while baking, it takes around 1 min time so i want to stop the print statement for that 1 min

Comment: well, what is the variable `baking` then? If you do not have that, you should just do `pool.apply_async(bake)`. Please clarify.

Comment: its a file name and bake is a function in it

Comment: Yes, in python you ignore the filename, it is not important. So then just call `bake()` or `pool.apply_async(bake)`

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you would use the `threading` module and its `join` method:

```
import threading    

def print_hello():
    for _ in range(3):
        print 'Hello'

hello_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_hello)
hello_thread.start()
hello_thread.join()

print "We're done!"
```

This code will print:

> Hello
>
> Hello
>
> Hello
>
> We're done!

So in your case you would create a thread:

```
bake_thread = threading.Thread(target=baking.bake)
```

Then simply `start` the thread and `join` with it.

Comment: but it didn't worked here, it is printing we're done! and next it is going to baking.bake() and executing around 1 min